# Replacing an over the range microwave with a wall range hood

Tags: kitchens

Hubby and I just purchased a new range and are looking to replace the over the range microwave with a wall mount range hood.

Floor to ceiling in the kitchen is 10'.
Range from floor to top of range is 37"
From top of the lower cabinets to the bottom of the upper cabinet (where the microwave sat) is 38"
The cabinet above where the microwave sat has duct work going to the exterior of the house, and an outlet.
We live on a two story house (so can't do chimney hood venting upstairs).

Questions:
 1. If Hubby is successfully able to take the cabinet directly above the microwave
    out, as a beginner, can he install the new wall hood himself?
 2. The duct work inside the cabinet (I don't have precise measurement) goes up ]
    approximately 12 inches, and then elbows outside.  Will this be sufficient
    for a wall mount hood (please note we still have ample space above the 
    cabinet, however prefer not to go that route).
 3. If hiring a pro is recommended, what is an approximate amount we should expect
    to pay (we live in Northern CA).

---

Below are all the measurements:

Distance from floor to Ceiling is 10 feet Distance from floor to to of the vent (before it elbows to the opening outside) is 81 1/2" Distance from the top of the 81 1/2" elbowing to the opening to the outside is a little over 4" The wide of the opening is 30" The height of the range is 37"

Hood measurements we are considering: 30" W x 24.0" D x 16.375" H

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Unfortunately, at least two of those questions are considered off-topic here. The first is completely subjective (and we know nothing of your husband's abilities or motivation anyway), the second depends on the products involved, and the third is specifically off-topic, per the [Help pages](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help). Please have a read over there and fee free to revise or delete and repost more specific and topical questions.

Answer (score 1):

The measurement that is relevant is the height of the bottom of the hood above the stovetop. This will determine what you would need to do to connect a given hood to your existing ductwork.

As far as the skill level to install a hood in a space occupied by a microwave oven, 25 years ago I did a similar project and I am not a skilled carpenter. I removed the 1970 builder's single unit range with double oven and installed a Vent-A-Hood (basic model) over a basic GE slide in electric range with single oven. I chose to put the bottom of the hood at 29" above the burner surface which I have found is too high for this quality of hood. A height of 24" to 26" would have allowed good visibility of food in deep pots on the back burners, but would improve effectiveness of the hood and would *possibly* decrease the noise level by getting the bottom of the hood below ear level.

To determine what height works for you (which depends on the height of the people doing the cooking and the depth of the pots) I suggest using a tape measure or a piece of cardboard across the opening to determine that you can see into the deepest pots you will use on the back burners.

> High-capacity range hoods are typically installed between 24 and 30
>   inches above the cooktop, while standard models are installed on
>   average between 18 and 24 inches above the surface of the cooktop.
>
> . . . Sometimes contractors prefer to measure the height of
>   the range hood they are installing from the floor rather than from the
>   surface of the cooktop. When this is the case, the bottom of the range
>   hood typically measures 60 inches from the floor.
>   https://www.hunker.com/12269148/what-height-to-put-a-range-hood

**EDIT**

You can arrange for the manufacturer of your kitchen cabinets to provide you with a cabinet which would support the hood and enclose the ductwork and the electrical receptacle for power to the hood. Then you could decide whether you want to try to install it yourself or hire a carpenter to do it yourself. Be aware though that measuring the space for a cabinet unit to fit between two already installed cabinets is tricky.